# find other files in same directory as XML file

Tags: xslt, uri, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to get content from another XML file in the same directory as my XML file. However, I don't know how to get the uri of the source XML. The XSLT keeps relating to its own directory.

How can I get the URI of the source XML?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend document-uri() rather than base-uri(). It will usually be the same, but base-uri() is affected by the xml:base attribute and by use of XML external entities, while document-uri() is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `base-uri()` function:

```
<!-- your external XML -->
<xsl:variable name="doc" select="document('http://www.xyz.com./path/your-doc.xml')"/>

<!-- the base URI of your external XML -->
<xsl:variable name="doc-base-uri" select="base-uri($doc)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is I don't know the XML doc name ahead of time. My XSL is part of an automated pipeline where the XML can be anywhere and named anything.

Comment: I see. In that case, perhaps your XSLT processor can set a parameter that you could read inside the XSLT with `<xsl:param>`. I don't think `base-uri()` works with documents that are sent as a stream, but the application that reads the docs can set that info as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that worked for me.
I got it using base-uri(.).